# Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize

I am using the `scipy.optimize.fsolve` function with the following code:

I am trying to solve the obj function for the value of `x_1` keeping the value of `x_2` constant. It should be noted that value of `x_1` and `x_2` are between 0 and 1.
I am adding the value of `w_xx`, `b_xx` and `y_test`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
y_test = np.array([3.448 ,11.071,3.602 ,11.838,3.512 ,13.78,4.013,15.209,3.339,13.15,3.387,17.419,3.793,15.303,3.92,11.683,3.655 ,14.317]).reshape(9,2)
#weight matrix
w_01 = np.array([0.5524624,0.72511494,0.51372594,-0.6308459]).reshape(2,2)
w_T2 = np.array([[-0.59752214, -0.5804831,   1.4108963,  -0.2634158,  -0.5614638,  -1.0390981, 0.65243214,  0.7106961, -0.5652963,  -0.0601576,   0.90772694, -1.3798463,  -0.40833127, -0.7003734, -0.21786042,  0.27037245]]).reshape(2,8)
w_02 = np.transpose(w_T2)
w_03 = np.array([[-1.0097426,0.32732514,0.24015452,-1.0950012,0.24607354,-0.21128657,-0.89929247,0.5828309,-1.4573368,-1.0770408,0.62045175,-1.2865094,-1.3986484,-1.2846812, 0.9638692 ,1.5144163]]).reshape(2,8)
#Bais matrix
b_01 = np.array([0.859291,0.59829414]).reshape(2,1)
b_02 = np.array([-0.5619188,-0.57078356,0.5717453,-0.5602762,-0.61745477,-0.6130685,0.56874627,0.55697656]).reshape(8,1)
b_03 = np.array([0.23421602,0.48550755]).reshape(2,1)
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
### Defining Obj function
### inp is 2x1 matrix and out is also 2x1 matrix
def objfunction(x1,x2,y):
    inp = np.array([x1,x2]).reshape(2,1)
    out = y.reshape(2,1)
    f = (np.dot(w_03,(np.dot(w_02,(sigmoid(np.dot(w_01,inp) + b_01))) + b_02)) + b_03) - out # value of y
    return f.flatten()
### Calculating Solution
x_1 = 0 ### Inital guess
x_2 = 0.5 
sol = np.zeros((len(y_test),2))
for i,value in enumerate(y_test):
    sol[i] = fsolve(objfunction,x_1,args=(x_2,value))
```

Error:

```py
p:\python\mimo_fsolve.py:46: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  inp = np.array([x1,x2]).reshape(2,1)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'

loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.ndarray which has no callable exp method
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You dumped a bunch of code (some of which is not formatted correctly). You should simplify the code down to just the bare essentials of what produces the error. Also, please share the error message as text, not an image.

Comment: Also, what does 2**1 shape mean? Do you mean (2,1) or 2x1?

Comment: I wanted to write 2x1 but I made an error. I have edited my post based on your comment. Please write if its is in correct format. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example is now missing definitions for all the `w_xx` and `b_xx` terms as well as `y_test`.

Comment: @jared I have updated the code with w_xx, b_ xx and y_test.  I also run the code and I am getting the error written above. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to only store `x_1` in `sol` or both `x_1` and `x_2`?

Comment: the important part of the error `ragged nested sequences`.

Comment: I wanted to store both `x_1` and `x_2` in `sol` but just storing value of `x_1` will work as well.

Comment: @hpaulj if I understand your comment well. I changed the line in code from `np.array([x1,x2]).reshape(2,1)` to `np.array([x1,x2],dtype = float).reshape(2,1)`. As the `x_1` and `x_2` both have decimal values. But there were still errors. Please advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: @hpaulj I saw that was the issue. I just wanted clarification on the desired result so I could figure out the right way to fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your main question, the reason you're getting this error is because `fsolve` is providing `objfunction` with a numpy array that looks like `np.array([x1])` for `x1`. When you try and combine this with `x2`, which is a float, to make `inp`, you create a ragged array since the first element is an array and the second element is just a number. Numpy doesn't like that so it turns the array into an `object` data type. You can see this if you try the following code:

```py
print(np.array([np.array([0]), 0]).dtype) # object
```

When you then try and do `np.exp` on the object array (because `inp` is an object data type, `np.dot(w_01, inp) + b_01` will also be), numpy throws an error because there is no implementation for `np.exp` on object arrays (reread the error and you'll see that that is what the error says).

To fix this, you can replace `x1` in your `inp` definition with `x1[0]`. But you'll end up with another issue because you're returning `f.flatten()`, which will be of shape `(2,)` since it contains `x2` while `fsolve` was expecting the return to be `(1,)` since that's what it gave the function. You can fix that by taking the first element (i.e. `f.flatten()[0]`). The last issue is that you defined `sol` to be `(n,2)`, but you only seem to want to store `x_1`, so just make it a 1D array.

```py
def objfunction(x1, x2, y):
    inp = np.array([x1[0], x2]).reshape(2, 1)
    out = y.reshape(2, 1)
    f = (np.dot(w_03, (np.dot(w_02, (sigmoid(np.dot(w_01, inp) + b_01))) +
         b_02)) + b_03) - out  # value of y
    return f.flatten()[0]


x_1 = 0  # Inital guess
x_2 = 0.5
sol = np.zeros((len(y_test)))
for i, value in enumerate(y_test):
    sol[i] = fsolve(objfunction, x_1, args=(x_2, value))
```